# Is there any good free windows xp tray calendar available?

Tags: windows-xp, calendar

Since our company had blocked administrator access to most members, the most important thing everybody is missing is to click on the clock and see the calendar.

Is there any good free windows xp tray calendar available?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**[LClock](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Clocks-Time-Management/LClock.shtml)** also comes with a simple but configurable popup calendar that opens when the systray clock is clicked. The calendar also contains reminder features.

No more double clicking on the clock just to view the calendar in the "Date and Time Properties" dialog box.

[image]

if you can't install software because of policy restrictions, you can also use LClock 'portable', just copy it from another computer to a USB stick and run lclock.exe.

Answer (score 2):

I like [Betaclock](http://www.betaclock.com/).  You can configure it to show up to 25 months (past or future), specify how they are displayed (I have a single column that includes last month and next), it allows you to modify the time display in your tray clock (I originally got it because I wanted to see seconds on the time display), synch to an atomic clock and a few other things.

[image]

Comment: You just made me switch from atomic clock to this ...

Answer (score 1):

I like the basic calendar included in [TClockEx](http://www.rcis.co.za/dale/tclockex/)

Comment: Huge fan of tclock, back to the days of two-tone.

Answer (score 1):

[Analog Clock](http://download.cnet.com/Analog-Clock/3000-2350_4-10461683.html) can display the time in analog or digital format and has a popout calendar when you click it:

[image]

Comment: this one again? did you actually test this program, John? you recommended it the last time for Windows 7 and it caused nothing but trouble in 7 for me, so i tried it with Windows XP SP3, program installs and starts the process but it does in fact NOTHING (mind you, a clean default installation, no fancy themes or so), the good thing though: it didn't cause explorer to crash as it did with Windows 7. :)

Comment: Molly stop trolling. It's getting annoying. The software works fine and I've tested it: http://i48.tinypic.com/317hchj.png

Comment: well, you did not respond to my first question where you recommended this program for Windows 7 so i keep asking for proof that it actually works. and i'm not trolling, au contraire, i'm ensuring the quality of recommendations made to users of this website. always looks better if you can vouch for what you recommend, doesn't it?